# Editing Build definition in TFS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build-definition

When I try to edit a build, mostly just to schedule it, visual studio 2010 crashes.

It gives the error: `an unhandled win32 exception occurred in devenv.exe(5692)`

Anyone know anything about this?

Have tried just creating a new build definition but get the same.

using TFS 2010 and VS professional 2010.

Thanks

Comment: Did you applied SP1 for VS and TFS? Does it crashes with `devenv.exe /safemode`?

Comment: No I haven't applied SP1, will do that now. How do you do `devenv.exe/safemode`?

Comment: First, make sure your environment is [up to date](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/03/23/keeping-your-tfs-2010-up-to-date-as-of-march-2012.aspx). If the problem persists, try [Devenv command line switches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx) (via Visual Studio Command Prompt)

Comment: It still crashes after I've installed the updates. I tried it in devenv.exe/safemode and it doesn't crash now. I also have another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047943/tfs-build-automation if you could look at that too, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To verify if one of the extensions could be causing the crash, use [Devenv Command Line Switches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx):

[`devenv /ResetSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273) and [`devenv /SafeMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx)

Comment: Running in safemode stops it from crashing. But `devenv /ResetSettings` doesn't seem to help as it still crashes when I edit build definitions.

Comment: Maybe the [`log`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272) switch may help for debugging

Comment: `devenv /log` ? I'll have to wait until monday to try it, thanks

Comment: What exactly am i looking for in the xml file?

Comment: Errors, warnings, traces of faults that help finding the root cause

Comment: Found the error, but don't know what it means `ERROR` `Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same ID 'd4f5086c-54b9-4b07-bd22-af72d5b9228f' is already loaded at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Telerik\Telerik.CommonPackage\1.0.7.0\...
          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Telerik\Telerik.CommonPackage\1.0.9.0\ `

Comment: It seems you have 2 versions of the same Telerik extension package. Try to uninstall it gracefully, if fails try to remove the older version by deleting the `1.0.7.0` folder. This package is linked with other [crash reports](http://www.google.com/search?q=d4f5086c-54b9-4b07-bd22-af72d5b9228f).

Comment: couldn't find a way to uninstall so deleted the folder. VS still crashes when I save a build definition. Used the `devenv /log` and there was no errors/warnings.

Comment: Hmmm.. Try submitting your issue on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/). Also check the event viewer for errors.

Comment: Have made a question on the Microsoft Connect http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vseditor/thread/1213d9f9-8855-41a0-a258-538f8cbd1fb0 thanks

Answer (score 2):

The following hotfix from Microsoft may be helpful:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/650386/vs2010-sp1-crashes-on-build-details-from-team-foundation-server-2008-build-explorer

Comment: Thanks, I've finished my work placement so not working with TFS now, but I'll forward it on.