# What resources exist for TFS 2012 RC build workflow?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2012

I have been an avid TFS user since 2005 but decided to skip the 2010 upgrade and jump directly to 2012. Does anyone have any recommended resources for learning about Workflow Foundation with respect to TFS build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with the links I suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11048228/383710). The [Wrox TFS 2012](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/1118314093/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?ie=UTF8&m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE) book is available on pre-order from Amazon, so it might be worth waiting and getting that book instead of the 2010 one. From what I have seen, the difference between 2010 and 2012 build processes is no where near as big as the gap between 2008 and 2010.